# PHPExcel causes problems

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to deal with Excel sheets in PHP and the following code causes irritating problems.

```
$getOrderFile = $this->db->query("SELECT order_file FROM orders WHERE id='".$order."'")->fetch_assoc();
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('xls/'.$getOrderFile["order_file"]);
$excelReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$Excel = $excelReader->load('xls/'.$getOrderFile["order_file"]);
return $Excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
```

Now, I checked the script with two variants of $getOrderFile["order_file"]:
1. excel1.xlxs
2. excel1.xls

When $getOrderFile["order_file"] equals excel1.xlxs - the page goes completely blank. There's no content displayed. And should there be any additional text in HTML - it isn't displayed. As if there was "exit;" somewhere but isn't.

When $getOrderFile["order_file"] equals excel1.xls - the pages goes "missing". I get "The webpage is not accessible" (404).

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? I just want to get the rowcount and... well. The whole system goes nuts.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So enable error logging, check logs for errors, check variable scope, etc.... we can't do your basic debugging for you

Comment: How are you actually calling this function? What do you do with the returned result?

Comment: All answers are in my post.

1. I'm calling this function the way it is ought to be called: $functions->getOrderNumber($id);

2. "I just want to get the rowcount"

That's for dealing with basics.

Comment: In that case, if that's all the information that you can provide, then I doubt that anybody can tell you what's wrong.... with no errors or exceptions, nothing written to error logs or webserver logs, about the only thing I can tell you is that PHPExcel is completely incapable of throwing a `"The webpage is not accessible" (404)."` message.... so there's certainly a lot more in your code that you're dismissing as irrelevant to the problem, but that is responsible for some of what you are seeing

Comment: I doubt that.

http://prntscr.com/3mhcu7
http://prntscr.com/3mhdc6

In the second image there is only 3 additional lines, one being db query. Should I remove $functions->getOrderEntries($Service["id"]), everything works perfectly.

Nobody will tell me it's, for instance, mysqli's fault

Comment: But you're basically telling me that it's PHPExcel's fault, yet not giving me any other information than "It doesn't work".... it could be a PHPExcel problem, but without a lot more information I can't even begin to guess what any problem might be.... you're using a method that works with all my own tests.... you don't even have error handling in place to help diagnose any problems.... I have no idea what your files might contain, etc.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what to debug. var_dump() does not produce anything, the page remains blank while the function is there. And I say it's phpexcel's fault for even when I remove the RETURN line from function, it's still the same.

All problems begin with this line: $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('xls/'.$getOrderFile["order_file"]);

Comment: I already conceded that it may be PHPExcel's fault..... but you're providing absolutely nothing to help diagnose the problem.... as a developer yourself, you should understand that I can't diagnose a problem if I can't replicate it in any way. I've been running tests for the last hour to see if I can get any valid Excel file to generate a blank page with no errors and nothing written to error logs, and I haven't managed to reproduce your problem.... invalid files return error messages, memory or timeout issues write to the logs; what more do you believe that I can do?

Comment: I understand that Mark, I'd have provided you with some details but I've got none... I've got errors turned on - nothing appears. I've checked it with var_dump() - nothing, replaced it with other PHPEx functions - nothing, the result is the same.

This is the reason I came here for any suggestions. I don't know how else I can debug this to get anything, I just don't. I can run PHPEx examples and they work. I even thought it's something with headers, but no... I just need hints... anything I can trace the problem with  ;x

Comment: You know, just to make sure, I made separate file http://prntscr.com/3mi8i9 without any external classes, without HTML and this is the output http://prntscr.com/3mi77r ("The webpage is not accessible").

Comment: Well knowing what versions of PHP and PHPExcel you're running always helps, together with knowing if you have the php_zip module working. The PHPExcel loader throws Exceptions, so a try/catch block around the PHPExcel code might help reveal something; knowing what a PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify() against the file returns would help; as would knowing whether the fault lies in `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile()` rather than in the call to `load()`

Comment: And if all you want to do is return the number of rows for a worksheet, then there is also a more efficient method call to the Reader's `listWorksheetInfo()` method is a lot faster to execute than loading the entire file

Comment: 1. PHP Version 5.2.5
2. PHPExcel 1.8.0
3. http://prntscr.com/3miop9 -> outputs completely blank page. Not even 'omg' is printed.
4. php_zip, php_gd2 and php_xml are on. They've been on by default.
No errors are written.

Comment: Okay, for this listWorksheetInfo() might do, but I need to read Excel file later anyway, so I need to get that solved.

Comment: You may need to `echo $e->getMessage();` in the catch blocks

Comment: If possible, would you be able to email me copies of the files as well? If something isn't working correctly, then being able to replicate the problem will help me work out what is happening, and I can put additional diagnostics in to work out what is going on.... the library has no problems with most files, so it's possible that this is something specific to the files that you're trying to load that most library users don't encounter

Comment: Nothing. Blank page. Error logs still empty. 

Sure thing - please give me your e-mail.

Comment: Use this link to download the files: http://www.speedyshare.com/E9r34/exc.rar

PHPExcel I'm using is already included. Waiting forward to hearing from you o7

Comment: Both files validate and load without issue, though I had to change the short open tag (`<?`) to a long open tag (`<?php`)

Comment: Tested using PHP versions 5.2.17, 5.3.27, 5.4.7, 5.4.21 and 5.5.5

Comment: Trying to find any changes between PHP 5.2.5 and 5.2.17 that would affect PHPExcel version 1.8.0

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Looking forward to hearing about the results. Anyway, maybe it would be better if I updated my PHP, perhaps? Does this script work for you with more actual versions?

Comment: Don't hold your breath waiting.... this is likely to be several days of work, and I do have a day job as well.... To test with other versions, I need to set up a PHP server with every version I test, that's a lot of work, so I'm not going to test against every individual of PHP that has been released since 5.2.0

Comment: But you're already running a version of PHP that's no longer supported, so it's a good idea to update to something more recent.... maintaining support for PHP 5.2 costs me a lot in time and effort, and prevents me from implementing changes that I know will improve memory usage and speed because they use features of PHP that weren't available in 5.2

Comment: Okay, updating. I'll let you know if that anyhow works. Thank you for all the support! o7

Comment: Problem solved.

Updated to PHP 5.4.x and it works perfectly. Thank you for that hint, Mark. You are priceless support!

Comment: PHP 5.4 should give you better memory usage and speed as well, just one of the benefits of upgrading; and it means you'll be ready for PHPExcel2 when I eventually get it ready for release